# Are Android xml files part of the class diagram

Tags: android, class-diagram

I am struggling to understand if we are supposed to include xml files in class diagrams. Basically, I have all xml files and linked them to their associated class where they are used? Is this correct? My diagram is below:

[image: Class Diagram]

Answer (score 1):

In a class diagram you must draw classes and their relationships. XML is a file format. In this case, I guess that the XML represents the screens of you Android App. You do not need to represent them in a class diagram to specify your Android app.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is an ibm.com link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/RationalEdge/sep04/bell/) that seemingly goes over very well what goes in a typical class diagram. However, if you're doing this for a professor, keep in mind any generalities offered here can be overridden by your professor's desires.

A snippet from the site:

> the purpose of the class diagram is to show the types being modeled within the system. In most UML models these types include:
>
> - a class
> - an interface
> - a data type
> - a component.
>
> [image: Example Class Diagram for a "Flight" class]

There are other diagrams that may include the GUI, but the CLASS Diagram isn't typically one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Android layouts may be referenced from and may themself have references to apllication classes. Without thoses XML files relations between classes are not fully explored. At least such XML layout files are needed on class diagramm.